# Can I blindly replace all mysql_ functions with mysqli_?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have used `mysql_query()` throughout my project; but I've just learned that `mysql_` was deprecated as of PHP 5.5, has been removed in PHP 7.

So, I would like to know if I can replace all `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_` in my project blindly? For example, just replacing `mysql_query()` with `mysqli_query()`. Is there any adverse effect?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The short answer is **no**, the functions are not equivalent.

The good news is there is a converter tool that will help you if you've got a lot of calls/projects to change. This will allow your scripts to work right away.

https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool

It's a forked version of the Oracle original version, and it's kosher.

That said, it's not too difficult to update your code, and you might want to migrate to an object orientated methodology anyway ...

**1) The Connection**

For all intents and purposes, you need a new connection function that saves the connection as a PHP variable, for example;

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
```

Notice I've saved the connection to `$mysqli`. You can save to `$db` or whatever you like, but you should use this throughout your code to reference the connection.

Remember to enable error reporting for mysqli before opening the connection;

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

**2) The Query**

*Note: You should protect against SQL injection with prepared statements, which are available in MySQLi. Take a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3899908), but I'm just going to cover the basics here.*

You now have to include the connection as an argument in your query, and other `mysqli_` functions. In procedural code it's the first argument, in OO you write it like a class method.

Procedural:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

OO:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

**3) Fetch Result**

The fetching of the result is similar to the old `mysql_` function in procedural;

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
```

but as `$result` is now an object in mysqli, you can use the object function call;

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
```

**4) Close Connection**

So as before, you need to include the connection in the close function; as an argument in procedural;

```
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

and as the object that you run the function on in OO;

```
$mysqli->close();
```

I would be here forever if I went through them all, but you get the idea. Take a look at [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for more information. Don't forget to convert any connection close, result release, or error and row counting functions you have.

The basic rule of thumb is for functions that use the database connection, you need to include it in the function now (either as the first argument in procedural, or the object you use to call the function in OO), or for a result set you can just change the function to `mysqli_` or use the result set as the object.

Comment: There is no kosher version of such a conversion. Any conversion should involve prepared statements. Otherwise it will make no sense at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense That's the difference between a conversion and a refactoring. Everyone should be refactoring their code to use prepared statements and I state that in my answer, but that's not the same as converting from `ext:mysql` to `ext:mysqli`, which is what this question is asking about.

Comment: The "new mysqli()" and "mysqli_query($link,$sqlStatement)" changes were hosing my page. Updated to Ubuntu 16, and the lamp stack came with php 7. All the old mysql functions were deprecated after 5.something. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you cannot convert all calls to the mysqli functions on a old project, you could install and include the library [php7-mysql-shim](https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim).

It will try to create a transparent replacement for mysql on PHP 7 using mysqli.
Obviously the performance is slower, but it's a solution to get around the problem in a couple of minutes.
You may safely include the library in projects working with PHP 5.6 (it will be ignored).

```
if (defined('PHP_VERSION_ID') && (PHP_VERSION_ID >= 50600)) { require_once "mysql-shim.php"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. some of the functions of mysql and mysqli require different parameters. So you should know which will use the same parameters.