# Converting from mysql_* to mysqli throws "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host_name'"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've just started to look into **mysqli**. When I make the **mysqli** connection with the database I am having a problem with the function.

**My Code:**

```
$link=mysqli_connect("host", "user","password","database_name", true) or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysqli_connect_error()); 

$query="CALL `database_name`.`table_name`('107','0100000000',63,122)";
  $result=mysqli_query($link,$query);
  $rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$image = $rs['image'];
$title = $rs['title'];

echo $title;

mysqli_close($link);
```

When I execute this in my PHP code it throws an error.

**Error:**

**`Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host_name' (110)`**

But when I use it with **MySQL** extension it works fine.

Comment: MySQL is not going to deprecate "soon" it is already deprecated since ages. Its going to be totally removed soon.

Comment: Use the right host name instead of `host_name`.

Comment: check the _mysql_*_ config and above.... they are not same. i can bet on that.

Comment: The 5th argument is the port number. `true` evaluates to `1` and that's not the correct port. Just remove this argument as it is not required. (in `mysql_connect()` the 5th argument was 'new link').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 5th argument in [`mysqli_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) is the port number.

`true` evaluates to `1` and that's not the correct port. Just remove this argument as it is not required - the default will be used.

In [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) the 5th argument was 'new link', so `true` was appropriate.

As you are just migrating to MySQLi, you might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/3899908) which gives you the basic changes from the old MySQL extension.

---

By the way, as you were using syntax for declaring a new connection, I thought you might want to know that you can have more than one connection when using mysqli. All you have to do is set it to a new variable, ie;

```
$link1 = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);
$link2 = new mysqli($host2,$username2,$password2,$database2);
```

Then you can choose the connection you use when executing queries etc. For example;

Procedural:

```
$result1 = mysqli_query($link1,$sql);
```

OO:

```
$result2 = $link2->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

The next aprameter after "database_name" is "port".

If you put true which evaluates to 1, you are trying to connect to port 1 (host_name:1)

Remove true or put the port of your MySQL Server incase you changed it
(3306 is the standard port for MySQL and doesnt require to be passed)

http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the argument "TRUE". It is not required as you see below.

Try this one

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    mysqli_select_db($link, 'database_name') or die ('I cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of connecting -

Syntax for connection:

```
mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);
```

Example;

```
//connection 
$con = mysqli_connect("myhostname","myusername","mypassw","mydatabase") or die("Error".mysqli_error($con)); 

//query
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytablename" or die("Error" . mysqli_error($con)); 

//execute 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```