# Get and output ID from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Currently i get the id with `<?= $store->id ?>` and it works fine

but i want to get the ID of mysql entry with

```
$id             =   $_GET['store_id'];
$query          =   "SELECT * FROM store WHERE id = '$id'";
$result         =   mysql_query($query);
$row            =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

or

```
$id             =   $_GET['$store->id'];
$query          =   "SELECT * FROM store WHERE id = '$id'";
$result         =   mysql_query($query);
$row            =   mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

and output with something like this `<?php print $row["id"];?>`

but it doesn't gives me the ID, it remains empty. What am I doing wrong? (I am aware working with mysql_... is not the best way, but that's not the problem now).

Comment: Are you sure `print $row["id"];` isn't empty?

Comment: yes, i think the problem is that `$_GET['store_id'];` doesn't get the id, but i don't understand why, cause `<?= $store->id ?>` is working

Comment: Please post whole code.

Comment: I know you said you know that `mysql_` functions are not the bast way, but you really need to stop using them. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/3899908) to get an idea of how to covert to `mysqli_`.

Comment: thank you for the converter

Answer (score 2):

If `$store->id` works fine for you, that means you're doing something wrong, and you defined `$store` earlier, IN your file. To get a param from the url, you need to use `$_GET["param"]`. If `$_GET["store_id"]` doesn't work then you didn't set an id in the url. If you want to get a param whose name is `$store->id`, then use `$_GET[$store->id]`, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

**DO NOT use mysql_* functions.** It takes only 2 minutes to change your code.

You do not need to select the current `downloads` to update it, you can do it via pure SQL: `UPDATE store SET downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE id = ?`

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to get ID from GET, your url must be like(Example)**

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/mypage.php?store_id=1234
```

Thus you will get

```
 $_GET['store_id'] // $_GET['store_id'] = 1234
```