# Changing from MySQL to MySQLi or PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

I have been working with PHP and MySQL for almost two years and I find that `mysql` is very easy to use, but it has security issues, and that's why I'm going to change from `mysql` to [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi), and I was wondering: is MySQLi more secure than the `mysql`?

And about MySQLi query: Should I just add an ' i ' to the old `mysql` like the following (just an example)?

`mysql`

```
if (mysql_query('insert into users (username, password, regdate)
                 values ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", "'.time().'")')) {
    echo 'Inserted!';
}
else
{
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

to MySQLi:

```
if (mysqli_query('insert into users (username, password, regdate)
                  values ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", "'.time().'")')) {
    echo 'Inserted!';
}
else {
    echo "something is wrong";
}
```

I've also heard about PDO and again: is PDO more secure than MySQLi?

Comment: best to read the manual before attempting to switch to mysqli http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: mysqli you provided is as unsecure as your mysql. You need to use prepared statements to protect you from SQL injection" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Comment: You can't just add an `i` to your `mysql` functions. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/3899908) for a few examples of what you need to change to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security issues come from what is known as [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In order to understand how to make it more secure you have to first understand how that works. Using a basic example of a really bad query:

```
   mysql_query('SELECT FROM user WHERE username="'.$_POST['username'].'" AND password="'.$_POST['username'].'"');
```

There are two main things wrong with this query. The first and most obvious is that values are added with no sanitation done on them. This is a classic example of SQL injection. In this example a user could submit a username, like this..

```
 'admin" --';
```

Now what is so bad with that? Because we are not filtering this (mainly for the quote) it makes our query look like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE username="admin" --" AND password="'.$_POST['username'].'"
```

To fully understand this you have to know that the `--` is the start of an inline comment ( much like `//` in PHP), and nothing after it is ran by the database. Given that, this is what we are left with.

```
 SELECT * FROM user WHERE username="admin"
```

Now if we were doing that for password validation by seeing if it returned a row, and had an account named `admin` which isn't unreasonable, we would have someone logged in without ever using a password.

The second issue that is less obvious is sending the password and using the query to validate. If we had structured it this way (psudo code):

```
   SELECT password FROM user WHERE username="admin"
   if( returned password == submitted password )
```

They would still need a password, because we are doing the evaluation in our code (application layer) and not in the database.

`mysql`, `mysqli` or `PDO` will not protect you if you inject variables.  PDO and [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) allow you to use prepared statements that take care of that issue. PDO is the better of the two if you ask me for the following reasons.

- Not dependent on the MySQL database (database agnostic)
- Allows named place holders, such as `:name` instead or just `?` indexed placeholders
- Better OOP support
- Generally supports more features

But neither one can keep you safe if you don't understand the threat.

Comment: Sure thing. Sometimes it just takes a simple explanation, and then it all clicks.  Glad I could help  point you down the road, keep trucking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to concatenate your queries, the security of the technology used does not matter much... That said, there is *[Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)*.