# Using php filter_var with mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to start my question by saying, I realize PDO/mysqli is the new standard and has been widely covered on SO. However in this particular case I dont have time to convert all queries to PDO before launching the clients site.

The following has been used throughout most of the queries on the site (not by me may I add)

```
  $userEmail = filter_var($_POST['fEmail'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   $userEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($userEmail);
   $sql ="SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = '$userEmail'";
   :
   :
```

**I would like to know:**

Is it good / okay practise to use `filter_var` and `mysql_real_escape_string` together as in the example above? My main concern is, can these two functions be used together or cause some sort of conflict / bug when executing / uploading to DB?

Also is there any sort of benefit in using both?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Your Common Sense with the risk of sounding like a school boy: in my question I mentioned `it was not me`...Im just scanning over the code and correcting/changing a few minor things before launch

Comment: Plus, the question received a downvote; which in my view was uncalled for. Had a certain someone "read" and "understood" what seems to be "clear/plain English" and in regards to the use of the MySQL API, then they'd quickly double back with their tail between their legs, or other means of running away. Some walk differently than other animals.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Sanitising* a string serves to make it conform to certain expectations. `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` removes any characters from a string which would be invalid in an email. The result is (supposedly) guaranteed to conform to email address syntax. How useful randomly removing characters from a string is I'll leave up to you. (Hint: I don't think it's very useful at all; you should rather reject invalid addresses than to transform them into random results. I give you an invalid email address, you hammer it into some shape that resembles an email address, now how do you know you'll be able to send me an email...?!)

`mysql_real_escape_string` is there to ensure that an arbitrary string does not violate SQL's string literal syntax by escaping all escape-worthy characters. Assuming you're using it correctly (lots of pitfalls mysql has, which is why it's deprecated...), there's nothing you can do to its input that would make it fail. You give it any arbitrary string, it returns you the escaped version, period.

As such, in general, yes, what you're doing is fine. If `mysql_real_escape_string` is the *last* thing you do to your string before interpolating it into an SQL string literal, then it's fine.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The radical anti-mysql faction. Yes, I'm looking at you, Col. Shrapnel. ;-)

Comment: My *spidey sense was tingling* as to a certain reptile roaming about. Yeah, I'm with you on this, *my sentiments exactly*.

Comment: For the record: yes, absolutely, `mysql_real_escape_string` is a terrible approach to the whole problem space... But the OP knows and this caveat is factored into the question and answer...

Comment: for what it is worth you got my vote thank you for the info

Comment: @deceze Indeed. Had people actually "read" what the OP wrote in regards to their use of the MySQL API, then there wouldn't be all this confusion.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, if the filter fails the query will be:

```
SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = '0'
```

So, not much to worry about the query; it just won't return any results.

Unless of course, you have a similar insert / update query.

In which case, you could have plenty of rows in the database where the email is `'0'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Probably someone who does not understand type casting from boolean to string I guess

Comment: *Meh,* let them eat (bean) cake.

Answer (score 2):

Using both is fine, but what you should really be doing is not to use `mysql_` at all. You should instead use `PDO` or `mysqli_` with prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Or for a guide of how to switch to MySQLi the see [Can I blindly replace all mysql_ functions with mysqli_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476162/can-i-blindly-replace-all-mysql-query-functions-with-mysqli-query/26476208#26476208)

Answer (score -3):

Your main concern should be this outdated approach, which is leaving your client's site vulnerable to SQL injection attack. 
While regarding this trifle matter of using yet another irrelevant function, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Your answer might actually be considered useful if you could show why this would be a vulnerability issue (since that *is* what the OP is concerned about), either a quotation from a reputable source or an example as to how to bypass whatever it is that mysql_real_escape_string pretends to do.