# PHP - simple login - does not see db

Tags: php, mysql

```
<body>
    <div class="login-card">
        <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
        <form action="incident-form.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login login-submit" value="Login">
        </form>

        <div class="login-help">
            <a href="#">Register</a> <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("aid");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                if ($row = ['password'] == $password){
                    echo "Successfully logged in!";
                }else{
                    echo "Wrong password";
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo "Username not found";
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm using phpMyAdmin with PHP 5.5. My db name is aid and table is users. The form is there, the db and table are there but it goes straight to the target page on submit without checking the users.

Comment: Change this: if `($row = ['password'] == $password){` to this: `if ($row['password'] == $password){`.

Comment: Reading through your question, are you expecting the php script to run on the form submit before the form moves to `incident-form.php`?

Comment: @RockMyAlgorithm, thanks but still does not work.

Comment: ... and stop using `mysql_` (especially since you are running PHP 5.5). Use [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26476162/3899908) or PDO instead.

Comment: Yes i'd like the php script to verify the user before going to the next page when the user is verified.

Comment: your form target is _incident-form.php_, is script above _incident-form.php_?

Comment: @Co2, try _Logan Wayne's answer_ and try to read about [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this also don't give the user a hint of what is wrong with the login also use the redirect function HERE IS THE CODE:

```
if (!function_exists('redirect_to')) {
   function redirect_to($new_location) {
      header("Location: " . $new_location);
      exit;
   } 
}
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aid");
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
                echo "Successfully logged in!";
                redirect_to("dashboard.php");
            } else{
                echo "Login Is wrong";
            }
        }
    } else{
        echo "Username/Password not found";
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: and also put your php above the html

Comment: Thanks very much, it works now but only if I take out the action to go to the next page. But I kinda need it to go to the next page after login. Now it just stays on the login page :/

Comment: depending on where the OP uses it, the security logic is correct, considering only users within a company are able to log in (where usernames are standard). If higher security is required then hinting should be removed.

Comment: @Co2i added the redirect function in the answer

Answer (score 5):

Change your `action` tag first.

```
<form action="" method="POST"> <!-- MEANS THAT PAGE WILL SUBMIT ON SELF FIRST -->
```

Your if condition inside your while loop should be:

```
if ($row['password'] == $password){
```

Then use `header()` to redirect user to `incident-form.php` if login is successful.

```
header("LOCATION:incident-form.php"); /* PUT THIS INSIDE YOUR IF CONDITION */
```

At least use [`*_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

But still, use `mysqli_*` rather than the [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) `mysql_*` API.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't work like that,  the server processes on a request sent. You will have to either move your code to the top of the `incident-form.php` and only show that content when it logs in or you will have to put this code on an page in-between, point the form there and use `header` functions to redirect or you would have to build a javascript call to the to the code and block the submit based on the result.

To expand a on a solution for you. You will need three pages

1. Your form which points to login-redirect.php
2. The login page which contains the following code

   ```
   $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "aid");
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST['password'];

       $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
       $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
               header("Location: incedent-form.php");
           } else{
               header("Location: login-form.php");
           }
       }
   } else {
       header("Location: login-form.php");
   }
   ```

   3. The incident-form.php