# Error: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `items`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while($prommes = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
}
```

When I'm running it. I'm getting this error:

> mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource.

Is it something wrong with my database?

And here is my connection which Irequire in the html document. Can it be something here which makes the query not working?

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);


// Check connection
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
// echo "Connected successfully";
```

Answer (score 0):

You never select a database, as far as I can tell, so $result is not a resultset (because the query never executes properly).  It is probably `false` instead.  You can var_dump it to verify that.  Try adding the database name in the query.  If your database is named `db`, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `db`.`items`;
```

If you don't want to explicitly specify the database name every time, you'll just want to add the database name to the MySQLi connection string, as shown:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop, `mysql_fetch_array` is incorrect. It should be

```
while($prommes = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

Additonally your connection needs to be

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

where `$database` is the name of your database (not the hostname).

As an aside, this can be better avoided using an object orientated approach. So for example, your connection could be;

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
```

and your query and loop could be;

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($prommes = $result->fetch_array())
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For a more detailed explaination of using OO mysqli, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/3899908)

Comment: And between mysqli_query() and while(mysqli_fetch_... [there must be error handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole). Every query can fail at any time.

Comment: @worldofjr where can I find the name of my database? Im using XAMP to setup it through localhost. It is not the name of the table that I want to use as "$database", right?

Comment: @Transk You're probably best installing phpMyAdmin so you can see your database structure.