# Error in my query when I try to delete data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete some data from a table in Workbench, but when I press the delete button I get this error;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Name='Stephenie Meyer' and Year_of_birth='1985'' at line 1.

This is the code:

```php
$author=$_POST['AuthorID'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$year=$_POST['Year_of_birth'];

$author=htmlspecialchars($author);
$name=htmlspecialchars($name);
$year=htmlspecialchars($year);

if($db_found)
{
      $SQL="SELECT*from books WHERE AuthorID='$author' Name='$name' and Year_of_birth='$year'";
      $result=mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
         {
             echo "<tr><td>".$row["AuthorID"]."</td><td>".$row["Name"]."</td><td>".$row["Year_of_birth"]."</td></tr>" ;

         }
         echo "</table><br>";
         $DQL="DELETE from books WHERE AuthorID='$author' , Name='$name' and Year_of_birth='$year'";
         if ($db_handle->query($DQL) === TRUE) 
           {
            echo "Record(s) deleted successfully";
           }
            else 
            {
            echo "Error deleting record: " . $db_handle->error;
            }
       }
       else
       {
          echo"Record not found";
       }
```

Can you please help?

Comment: And required between name and author instead of comma for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put a logic operator between all your `WHERE` conditions.

```
SELECT*from books WHERE AuthorID='$author' Name='$name' ...
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE AuthorID='$author' AND Name='$name' ...
```

and also

```
DELETE from books WHERE AuthorID='$author' , Name='$name' ...
```

should be

```
DELETE FROM books WHERE AuthorID='$author' AND Name='$name' ...
```

---

Incidently, `mysql_` functions are deprecated. You should use MySQLi or PDO instead. Additonally, your query is open to SQL injection; read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/3899908)

Comment: @SofiaV Happy to help; but please do take notice of the second part. `mysql_` functions have been removed in the latest version of PHP, so you do need to change all your database methods. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26476208/3899908) for info of how to migrate to MySQLi.

Comment: I changed that as well. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of syntax errors.

1. You left out an `AND`
2. Add some spaces

Change:

```
 $SQL="SELECT*from books WHERE AuthorID='$author' Name='$name' and Year_of_birth='$year'";
```

to

```
 $SQL="SELECT * FROM books WHERE AuthorID='$author' AND Name='$name' AND Year_of_birth='$year'";
```

Also please look into more modern ways of doing a MySQL query in PHP instead of `mysql_query`. It was deprecated. Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php